# jquery how to remove the hide event of class

Tags: php, jquery, html

i had a class that hides div,

```
$(".trueQuestions").hide();
```

then if i click on a button i want to remove this class' hide effect

```
$(".btnOK<?php echo $sub_category.$counter; ?>").click(function(){
//this is what i did
$("#trueQuestions").removeClass("trueQuestions");
});
```

i tried remove class event but the hide event is still firing.
is there any event that can remove the hide effect?
I will appreciate the help. thanks!

Comment: show your HTML. It will help us see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think youre getting confused on how the events are working.

Your JS is currently doing the following:

1. hide the element with class `trueQuestions`
2. attach the event `click` to the class `btnOK..`
3. the `click` event will remove the class `trueQuestions` from the element with ID of `trueQuestions`

so, the problem is really happening in your understanding of that happens when you remove the class. When you remove the class, in your case, it does not remove any events because none were attached, it just simply removes the class along with any CSS associated with it. If events were attached to it, it would do that as well, however your first line of code `$(".trueQuestions").hide();` simply added a inline style of `display:none` to the `.trueQuestions` element, it did not attach an event to the element.

In order to fix it, you need some CSS. The class will hold the CSS you want, so that when you remove it, it removes the CSS along with it. Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn">btn</button>
<div id="trueQuestions" class="hide">
    content
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("#trueQuestions").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

Here you hide  class trueQuestions

```
$("#trueQuestions").css('display', 'none')
```

Here you display it

```
$("#trueQuestions").css('display', 'inline');
```

or

```
$(".trueQuestions").hide(); // hide
$(".trueQuestions").show(); // show
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried it but it does the same. but i just to clarify that i just want this trueQuestion class to hide my div and remove the hide event when i click the ok button;